# will the dataframe.write.save() fail if the --driver-memory is less than the data to be written in PySpark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

We have a dataframe with 5 columns and nearly 1.5 Billion records.

We want to write that as a single line (single record) json.

We are facing two issues

1. `df.write.format('json')` is writing as single line or single record but there is second line that is empty and we want to avoid it
2. `df.write.format('json').save('somedir_in_HDFS')` is giving error

We want to save the data as single file so that the downstream application can read it

Here is the sample code.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *


schema = StructType([
    StructField("author", StringType(), False),
    StructField("title", StringType(), False),
    StructField("pages", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("email", StringType(), False)
])

#likewise we have 1.5 billion records
data = [
    ["author1", "title1", 1, "author1@gmail.com"],
    ["author2", "title2", 2, "author2@gmail.com"],
    ["author3", "title3", 3, "author3@gmail.com"],
    ["author4", "title4", 4, "author4@gmail.com"]
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    dfprocessed=df #here we are doing lots of joins with other tables
    dfprocessed = dfprocessed.agg(
        f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col('author'), f.col('title'), f.col('pages'), f.col('email'))).alias("list-item"))
    dfprocessed = dfprocessed.withColumn("version", f.lit("1.0").cast(IntegerType()))
    dfprocessed.printSchema()
    dfprocessed.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").option("escape", "").save('./TestJson')
    #the above write adds one extra empty line
```

submit command

```
spark-submit --conf spark.port.maxRetries=100 --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
    --executor memory 16g --executor-core 4 --driver-memory 16g
    --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g 
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
    --cong spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutor=30
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutor=15
    --code.py
```

error

```
"Error occurred in save_daily_report : An error occurred while calling o149.save.
:org.apache.spark.sparkException:Job aborted
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasource.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)    
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasource.InsertIntoHadoopFSRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFSRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(command.scala:104)
    ...
    ..
    ..
    caused by org.apache.spark.sparkException:Job aborted due to stage Failure:Task 26 in stage 211.0 failed 4 times,most recent
    failure:Lost task 26.3 in stage 211.0 
    ExecutorLostFailure(executor xxx exited caused by one the the running task)Reason:Container maked as failed
    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
    Killed by external signal
    
    Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failedJobAndIndependent
    Stages (DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
```

Why would the above code fail? How do we resolve the error?

Comment: re: point 1, I'm not able to replicate your issue on spark 3.1.2 -- it does not write blank line in my test using your code.

Comment: @samkart Thanks for the response. Can you help me with the error. why it giving this error where are tyring to write.1.5 billion records in json as single line